# Extender controls of type 'AjaxControlToolkit.AlwaysVisibleControlExtender' cannot extend controls of type 'System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel'

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajax

Extender controls of type 'AjaxControlToolkit.AlwaysVisibleControlExtender' cannot extend controls of type 'System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel'.

I am using AjaxControlToolkit.AlwaysVisibleControlExtender and trying to update the UpdateProgress that time it is showing above metnioned error.

Please suggest me solutions to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this problem but I was using a div.  Basically with the new version it is requiring using an asp:Panel.  This fixed it for me.